# AsyncTask and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to load a ListView using a RecyclerView, but only the progress bar is the one loading and the list is not showing . I'm using Firebase in the AsyncTask class. Where am I going wrong? Below is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public static String KEY_HEADLINES="headlines";
    public static String KEY_DETAILS="details";

    ProgressBar pb;

   public  List<NewsModel> newslist;

   public NewsAdapter2 adapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private DatabaseReference mRef;
    ImageView image_news;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // call the array list
        newslist = new ArrayList<NewsModel>();

        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarNews);
        image_news =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_news);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        //Enabling offline capabilities
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

         // firebase initialisation......
        mRef =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("News");
        // keep my data synced
        mRef.keepSynced(true);


//firebase

        //initializing async task
  new  MyTask();

        // load data

        //declare the toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    public void LoadData (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());

        NewsModel news_model =dataSnapshot.getValue(NewsModel.class);

        newslist.add(news_model);

        adapter = new NewsAdapter2(MainActivity.this, newslist);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Intent i;
        if (id == R.id.hospitals) {
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HealthCentres.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.doctors) {
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Doctors.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.tips) {
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tips.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
        else if (id == R.id.contacts) {
            i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactUs.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
        else if (id == R.id.about) {
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                LoadData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                LoadData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}















}
```

Comment: I reduced the code a bit, but it's still ridiculously much. Please read this article on [how to provide the minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Firebase has already it's Asynchronous litsener , so what you can do put this in the `onCreate` Method. But you said that the progress bar is the only visible , just also add this code of line in the `onChildEventLitsener()` method `pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`, so that when data comes the Progress bar dissapears.

```
mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                LoadData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                LoadData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Hope this works well.

Answer (score 1):

1. A listener on a `FirebaseReference` is an  **asynchronous listener**, you don't need to wrap it with an `AsyncTask`. You only need to set the listener:

   ```
    mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { 
       //... methods here
   });
   ```

   You can't really detect if Firebase is currently loading, because it triggered everytime data changes. But you can remove the listener if you want to stop the sync:

   ```
    mRef.removeEventListener();
   ```

   Please read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data).
2. Don't create a new adapter each time you receive data. Check if it is null, if not, only do a `notifyDatasetChanged` (or a method directly pointing to the change).

Comment: Now so you mean its impossible to put a progress bar to load while waiting for data , , please show me how it's done if it's possible to load a progress bar before a list @Amylinn.

Comment: When you are sure that you have data, you can show a loading indicator if the list is empty, and hide it when its not. Or put a timer on it if you don't have data and then show something like "no data".

Comment: am new in this please show me how , like edit the code . please

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of asyntask for addng listener, by creating in async it's scope is limited to life of asyntask. So put the listener in oncreate/ onresume itself

```
 mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                LoadData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                LoadData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: So how can i make my progress bar loads first then , the data comes, please can you show me that approach @deepakjohn. Coz i did that in the first place

Comment: For sure @deepak , i gone through the docs , but am confused on how i can attach a progress bar to load before data coming, am not getting a clue on the docs , if you know please help :)