# Storing firebase values into an array? Keep getting zero

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase

I am trying to store userid's into uidMatches. When I do the first println I am getting the correct string array of matches, but when i do the second one it says my uidMatches array has nothing in it... "[ ]". I don't see how this is possible.

```
 private void populateListView() {
    final ArrayList<String> uidMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayList<Profile> match_profiles = new ArrayList<Profile>();
    users = database.getReference("Users");
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    matches = database.getReference("Matches").child(user.getUid());

    // Returns uid's for all profiles you matched with
   matches.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String match = child.getValue().toString();
                uidMatches.add(match.toString());
               System.out.println("HERE ARE MATCHES 1: " + uidMatches);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    System.out.println("HERE ARE MATCHES 2: " + uidMatches);



// Loop to get all Profiles that match each "uidMatches" uid
 for (int x=0; x<uidMatches.size(); x++)
    {
        users.child(uidMatches.get(x)).addValueEventListener(new     ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Profile profile = child.getValue(Profile.class);
                    match_profiles.add(profile);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

[Picture of my firebase setup. I Blocked out the users unique ID's generated from FB login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH7xk.png)

Comment: Without running your code I think I see the problem. The println at the end of your code gets run when the code first starts when the array is empty. The other println gets fired onDataChange so after the results are populated.

Comment: Check out my database please, I put the overall layout. I am trying to use the uidMatches to find all User Objects matching the the id's so that I can get back user Attributes. Am i better off storing user objects under matches rather than just a string of their uid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a firebase issue it's simply a Java problem. The println at the end of your code gets run when the code first starts when the array is empty. The other println gets fired onDataChange so after the results are populated.

Comment: I am trying to use the uidMatches to find all User Objects matching the the id's so that I can get back user Attributes. Am i better off storing user objects under matches rather than just a string of their uid? Im uploading a pic of my whole DB now with the users attributes too.

Comment: If the only thing you store is a string of their ID then you will have to make another database call to get their attributes

Comment: Thats what i was trying to do. But How can I reference the uid for the person matched with if the array won't store the id for that user? I don't know which unique id under "Users" to reference

Comment: I want to make sure I clarify what is currently happening with your program. When you run it currently it prints out "HERE ARE MATCHES1: " with the id list after it for each array item but "HERE ARE MATCHES2: " doesnt have any ids after it?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what's happening. I uploaded the other event listener in my code so you can see exactly whats it looks like. Sorry i was trying to keep the code short and sweet

Comment: You could add a method call to the first even listener so when it changes it gets the user and prints it (or whatever you want) I am unfamiliar with firebase but it seems that this is an async call so it doesn't wait for the array to be populated before it continues execution. This means that you either have to use some mechanism to stop execution until you get the results you want or you can embrace the async nature and use additional async listeners to work with the data when it is returned

Comment: I think i got it, Thank You! Im gonna check this out, I searched for firebase async and found it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744213/asynctask-and-firebase